# OnBackPressed for each item in the NavigatorView

Tags: java, android, navigation, fragment

There is a `NavigatorView` in which I am using the `NavController`. The whole problem is that when replacing the Fragmenta, I immediately set `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack (String.valueOf (FragmentRink3));` and when navigating to another `NavController` when clicking on `OnBackPressed`, is applied to the fragment from the previous `NavController` where the replacement was made. It's hard to explain. Is it possible to somehow do so that each of the lower navigation menu has its own, I don’t know, a list of clicks, according to which the sequence of transitions to fragments was determined? I know I explained very poorly, I will attach a gif to show the problem clearly.

[image]

As you can see, by clicking on the button, the fragment was replaced, then I went to the next menu and clicked `OnBackPressed`, and at this moment the fragment, which was replaced in the previous menu, went back. How to fix it?

I will replace the `fragment` as follows:

```
btn_close.setOnClickListener(v ->
        {
            FragmentRink4 fragment = new FragmentRink4(); // you fragment
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(); // instantiate your view context
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_controller_rink1, fragment);// your container and your fragment
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(String.valueOf(FragmentRink3));
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        });
```

[Here is a link to the project.](https://github.com/Karp-but-not-fish/Navigation)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand. but as I guess, when you click on back, you go to the fragments which you were before, and it doesn't go to the main fragment or exit app immediately after reaching or been in the main fragment. am I right?

Comment: @A.R.B.N After clicking on the button, the fragment is replaced, and no matter what phagemet I would be in when clicking on OnBackPressed, the fragment in which the last replacement was returned is returned